# Покупка Конфет Задача c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

Условие задачи на картинке, в своем коде не вижу ошибок, на 1 из 20 тестов проваливает, подскажите в чем ошибка?

[image: Задача]

Мой код :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

ifstream inp;
ofstream otp;
inp.open("input.txt");
otp.open("output.txt");

int a[101], ans[4], n = 0, max1 = 0, max1n[5], max2 = 0, max2n[5], x = 0;

inp >> n;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    inp >> a[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    x = a[i] + a[i + 1];
    if (x > max1) {
        max1 = x;
        max1n[0] = i;
        max1n[1] = i + 1;
    }
    else {
        continue;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    x = a[i] + a[i + 1];
    if (x > max2) {
        if (i != max1n[0] && i + 1 != max1n[0] && i != max1n[1] && i + 1  != max1n[1]) {
            max2 = x;
            max2n[0] = i;
            max2n[1] = i + 1;
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    else {
        continue;
    }
}

otp << max1n[0] + 1 << " " << max1n[1] + 1 << " " << max2n[0] + 1 << " " << max2n[1] + 1;


return 1;
```

}

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85512/discussion-on-question-by-valeragrinenko----c).

Comment: Задача сводится к нахождению индексов четырех максимальных элементов, по парам находящихся рядом

Comment: Мда. Три ответа - и все три не отвечают на вопрос. :\

Comment: @HolyBlackCat что не так в коде писалось раз 5 в комментариях) но ответ "ошибка в логике, вот тест" не тянет на ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение за чистый O(n). Упражнение - переписать используя только константую память (не читать массив целиком).

```
int main() {

    int n, a[100], mPrex, mRes, res[3];

    cin >> n;
    for (int i=0;i < n;i++)
        cin >> a[i];

    res[0] = 1;
    res[1] = 1;
    res[2] = 3;
    mPrex = a[0] + a[1];
    mRes = mPrex + a[2] + a[3];
    for (int i=3; i < n-1;i++){
        if (a[i-2] + a[i-1] > mPrex){
            mPrex = a[i-2] + a[i-1];
            res[0] = i-1;
        }
        if (mPrex + a[i] + a[i+1] > mRes){
            mRes = mPrex + a[i] + a[i+1];
            res[1] = res[0];
            res[2] = i+1;
        }
    }
    cout << res[1]<<" "<<res[1] + 1 << " "<<res[2]<<" "<<res[2] + 1;
    return 0;
}
```

В чём собственно задумка. Мы можем легко поддерживать где в массиве был максимум до какой-то позиции. Поэтому мы перебираем правую пару, а левая пара - максимум из всего что было до правой. Правая пара начинается с позиции `i` в цикле что от 3. Дальше вроде бы всё понятно.

Answer (score 0):

a[]-массив количества конфет
n-длина массива

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    a[i]=a[i]+a[i+1];

n--;
int x;

for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    for (int j = i+2; j < n; j++){
        if(j-i>1){
            x=a[i]+a[j];
            //cout <<"i="<<i<<";\tj="<<j<<";\tx="<<x<<";\tmax="<<max<<endl;//для отладки
            if (max<x){
                max=x;
                res[0]=i;
                res[1]=j;
            }
        }
    }
for (auto x : res)
     cout << x+1<<" "<< x+2<<" ";
return 0;
```

https://ideone.com/n8W7Zh

Comment: тут тоже ошибка есть. И да выход за границы гарантирован) https://ideone.com/qyznR3

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko что скажешь?

Comment: исправил выход за границы при i==n-2

Comment: неверный ответ на том же тесте. по моей ссылке.

Comment: @pavel а где ты тестишь?

Comment: сам тесты подбираю. Я вижу ошибку в логике и подбираю пример на эту ошибку.

Comment: Все тесты кроме 1 неверные, тот что верный не тот что нужен.

Comment: вернул длинную проверку) - тут она нужна

Comment: @dgzargo 2 теста неверные, тот что был неверным сначала(с моей версией кода) работает!

Comment: @dgzargo опять неверная логика) {1,55,57,53,51,1}

Comment: @pavel а вы сможете привести пример правильно работающего кода ?

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko могу конечно. Но зачем? В процессе таких обсуждений мне кажется полезнее самому дойти до своих ошибок. А если вас срочно сдать надо так `for () for () for () for () if (){ .. ]` успеет

Comment: @pavel не понимаю что вы постоянно говорите про 4уровневый цикл, чем он мне поможет?

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko https://ideone.com/1nYWzx

Comment: @pavel полностью изменил решение (мое изначальное)

Comment: Ну я это уже в комментарии писал) а теперь за линейно а не за квадрат сможете?)

Answer (score 0):

решение за O(n)

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    x = a[i] + a[i + 1];
    if (x > max1) {
        max1 = x;
        max1n[0] = i;
        max1n[1] = i + 1;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    x = a[i] + a[i + 1];
    if (i != max1n[0] && i + 1 != max1n[0] && i != max1n[1] && i + 1  != max1n[1]) {
        if (x > max2) {
            max2 = x;
            max2n[0] = i;
            max2n[1] = i + 1;
        }
    }
    else {//если числа пересекаются
        if(i+1 == max1n[0] && i+3<n){
            x = a[i] + a[i+1] + a[i+2] + a[i+3];//смотрю сумму после сдвига
            if (x>max1+max2){//если она мне нравится
                max1n[0] = i;//записываю как текущий результат
                max1n[1] = i+1;
                max2n[0] = i+2;
                max2n[1] = i+3;
            }
        }
    }
}
    cout << max1n[0] + 1 << " " << max1n[1] + 1 << " " << max2n[0] + 1 << " " << max2n[1] + 1;


return 0;
```

https://ideone.com/Z5U0sG

Comment: `53 55 57 53 58 1` неправильный ответ.